# Aftermarket Radio Issues

Tags: honda, audio, pilot

So I have a 2007 Honda Pilot. The radio has been replaced by an aftermarket one, the Pioneer FH-X700BT. When I turn the car on the first bit, the whole system works wonderfully, no glitches. However, as soon as I put it in reverse and then into drive and start accelerating, the songs will skip. Especially with the USB/iPod port, or through bluetooth. The songs will just skip to the next one, or the output changes to display the time left on the song and then starts to reverse it all the way down. I literally have no clue what is going on, but any help would be greatly appreciated. This only started two days ago, but I figured I should get help as quick as possible. Thank you all.

Comment: Possibly a bad Pioneer unit, who installed it?

Comment: Not sure. It was installed nearly 8 years ago while I was away as this is my dads car that I bought from him. Only just hit 100k on the odometer a few weeks ago, so it's still in amazing condition. The unit is the only thing giving me issues now. Could it be from how old it is?

Comment: Its an odd issue that I have never encountered before, might be easier in the long run to try another head unit.

Comment: I've had found Pioneer head units to be finicky in general, but more so when the vehicle charging system gets worse. Excessive alternator ripple or voltage changes seem to make them loose their mind. How old is your battery? Do you have whining or other audio noise, (esp. with higher RPMs) coming through the speakers? How old is the alternator and has it been tested? (Even if it's the charging system I'd still probably change the radio, but it's always nice to know why.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to figure this one out. It sounds like hocus pocus, but there must be a reasonable hypothesis that might be considered practical enough to be an answer.

### Hypothesis #1:

Vibration from worn engine mounts is being transferred through the body and may have caused the radio electronics to fail. This explains why it works when the car is in park. Test this by turning the radio on with the engine off. Give the dash a couple of whacks after some minutes to see if the radio starts misbehaving (this introduces vibration).

### Hypothesis #2:

You have a bad alternator and its sending a higher voltage than what the radio can handle. The alternator will send about 13.3V - 13.9V at idle. This should only increase a little when the engine speed increases. A bad alternator may continue to increase voltage as engine speed increases. Anything over 14.5V means the voltage regulator is not doing its job. Connect a multimeter to the battery terminals with the engine running. Measure the voltage with the engine at idle and with the engine at 3-4K RPM.

### Hypothesis #3:

You have a bad radio ground. Pull the radio and check that the ground is secured correctly. The ground is usually part of the radio harness. In some cases, where the person who installed did a bad job (if its you then shame on you), the ground might be connected to a screw on the dashboard.

### Hypothesis #4:

An electronic component inside the radio failed. As you use your radio, the temperature in the circuits increases causing faulty components to fail. You can fix this by taking it to a electronics repair shop, **but** the parts might not be available or it will be more expensive than buying a new radio instead.

### Hypothesis #5:

Pioneer needs to sell more radios and yours failed as a result. Their current stock price is [242 Yen](https://secure.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/6773).

To quote the Car Talk hosts:

> Doesn't anybody screen these questions?

Answer (score -1):

After 8 years, I wouldn't even troubleshoot it. Just put a new unit in.